# Int Option instead of Int in F#

Tags: f#, integer, option-type, f#-interactive

I am having trouble with the following:

```
let safeDiv x y = 
  match (x,y) with
  | (_, Some 0) -> None
  | (Some xx, Some yy) -> Some (xx/yy)
  | _ -> None
```

When I go to run this simple function in the interactive window of Visual Studio like so:

```
safeDiv 4 2
```

I get the following error...

> This expression was expected to have type int option but here has type int.

Could it be I'm meant to use `safeDiv` `Some(4)` `Some(2)`? This doesn't work either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is overkill but I actually did something similar to this recently.

First I defined a computation expression builder for the option type:

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member this.Bind(x, f) = Option.bind f x
    member this.Return(x) = Some x
    member this.ReturnFrom(x) = x

let opt = new OptionBuilder()
```

And then I defined a function sub of type float -> float -> float option

```
let sub x y = if y = 0.0 then None else Some (x / y)
```

And finally I used the OptionBuilder to define saveDiv as float option -> float option -> float option

```
let safeDiv x y = opt { let! a = x
                        let! b = y
                        return! sub a b }
```

You can read more about computation expressions on wikibooks: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions

And if you want to dive deeper into the theory behind this, you can read this paper by Tomas Petricek and Don Syme: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tp322/drafts/notations.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your second version was close.

It should be

```
safeDiv (Some(4)) (Some(2))
```

The extra brackets are required to make sure that functions are applied in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You constructed a function that has the signature `safeDiv : int option -> int option -> int option`. You need to use an entry like `safeDiv (Some 4) (Some 2)` to use your function as is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the matching of (4, 2), of type int*int, with the expressions (_, Some 0) and (Some xx, Some yy). The whole function can be simplified:

```
let safeDiv x y = 
    match (x,y) with
    | (_, 0) -> None
    | (_, _) -> Some (x/y)
```

Making the following call valid

```
safeDiv 4 2
```