# Overloading operators in type extensions

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, inline, option-type

Ok, so I'm basically trying to add the bind operator to the option type and it seems that everything I try has some non-obvious caveat that prevent me from doing it. I suspect is has something to do with the limits of the .NET typesystem and is probably the same reason typeclasses can't be implemented in user code.

Anyways, I've attempted a couple of things.

First, I tried just the following

```
let (>>=) m f = ???
```

realizing that I want to do different things based on the type of `m`. F# doesn't allow overloads on function but .NET does allow them on methods, so attempt number two:

```
type Mon<'a> =
    static member Bind(m : Option<'a>, f : ('a -> Option<'b>)) =
        match m with
        | None -> None
        | Some x -> f x
    static member Bind(m : List<'a>, f : ('a -> List<'b>)) = 
        List.map f m |> List.concat

let (>>=) m f = Mon.Bind(m, f)
```

No dice. Can't pick a unique overload based on previously given type info. Add type annotations.

I've tried making the operator inline but it still gives the same error.

Then I figured I could make the `>>=` operator a member of a type. I'm pretty sure this would work but I don't think I can hack it in on existing types. You can extend existing types with `type Option<'a> with` but you can't have operators as extensions.

That was my last attempt with this code:

```
type Option<'a> with
    static member (>>=) (m : Option<'a>, f : ('a -> Option<'b>)) =
        match m with
        | None -> None
        | Some x -> f x
```

"Extension members cannot provide operator overloads.  Consider defining the operator as part of the type definition instead." Awesome.

Do I have any other option? I could define separate functions for different monads in separate modules but that sounds like hell if you want to use more than one version in the same file.

Comment: @JohnPalmer Oh, sorry. The point was to have more than one overload for the Bind method. Then it throws an error. I'll fix it in the question.

Comment: I think your problem is that you would something like Type-constructors to give a reasonable type for a general (>>=) (remember a Monad has kind * -> *) - static constraints on inline functions will not help because of this too - so no, you are out of luck.

Comment: I sometimes wrap those operators inside a inner module (often named just Operators) - so I can just `open MyMonad.Operators` if I want those - or have to `MyMonad.Operators.>>=` :(

Comment: If you are truly desperate, you can always modify `Option.fs`

Comment: @JohnPalmer +1 - but why? `opt >>= (fun x -> ...` seems not much better than `opt |> Option.bind (fun x -> ...` to me

Comment: @CarstenKönig A possible motivation may be to get rid of the parentheses, e.g. `opt >>= fun x -> ...`, and another, you can get away with the same top-level indentation. All your `fun` lines up at the same level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine .NET overload resolution with inline/static constraints in order to get the desired behaviour.

Here's a step by step [explanation](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/index.php/inlinefun) and here's a small working example for your specific scenario:

```
type MonadBind = MonadBind with
    static member (?<-) (MonadBind, m:Option<'a>, _:Option<'b>) = 
        fun (f:_->Option<'b>) ->
            match m with
            | None -> None
            | Some x -> f x
    static member (?<-) (MonadBind, m:List<'a>, _:List<'b>) = 
        fun (f:_->List<'b>) ->
            List.map f m |> List.concat

let inline (>>=) m f : 'R = ( (?<-) MonadBind m Unchecked.defaultof<'R>) f

[2; 1] >>= (fun x -> [string x; string (x+2)]) // List<string> = ["2"; "4"; "1"; "3"]
Some 2 >>= (fun x -> Some (string x))          // Option<string> = Some "2"
```

You can also specify the constraints 'by hand', but when using operators they're inferred automatically.

A refinement of this technique (without the operators) is what we use in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) to define Monad, Functor, Arrow and other abstractions.

Also note you can use directly `Option.bind` and `List.collect` for both bind definitions.

Comment: Nice! Should I use FsControl or fsharp-typeclasses?

Comment: @LukaHorvat fsharptypeclasses was an initial experiment/demo project. Use instead FsControl which was designed to be used as a core lib for production F# projects.

Comment: It's been a while, but this now gives an error on `List.map f m |> List.concat` (expecting `'a list` instead of `'b list`) and on the lines that apply the `>>=` operator. It wasn't immediately obvious what caused this, esp assuming it was probably correct 10 years ago.

Comment: Funny, it still works for me. Let's chat and see if you're doing something wrong or there is a new breaking change in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to (re-define) "bind"? For starters, Option.bind is already defined.

You can use it for defining a "computational expression builder" (F# name for monadic "do" syntax sugar).
See [previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240262/int-option-instead-of-int-in-f)